# in a pandas dataframe return a numeric substring from a string without specifying indexes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a few examples of dataframes, where text or numeric data I want to extract aren't always in the same column or row, or indeed in the same order n different strings:

df:

```
{1: {0: 'sample', 1: 2},
 2: {0: 'project: 4568 date: 7 January 2023', 1: 4},
 3: {0: 'substance:water', 1: 6}}
```

df2:

```
{1: {0: 'sample', 1: 2},
 2: {0: 'user ab', 1: 4},
 3: {0: 'project: 4568 date: 7 January 2023', 1: 6},
 4: {0: 'substance:water', 1: 3}}
```

df3:

```
{1: {0: nan, 1: 'sample', 2: 2},
 2: {0: 'Monday', 1: 'user ab', 2: 4},
 3: {0: nan, 1: 'project: 4568 substance: water date: 7 January 2023', 2: 6},
 4: {0: nan, 1: 'plate 2', 2: 3}}
```

I'd like to extract the numeric value (which always starts with a 45, and is always 4 digits) that comes after 'project:', and the date and substance from these dataframes into their own variable.

In the example of the project number, could do this by:
`a=df.iloc[0,1].split(' ')[1]` to get the project number, and `b=df.iloc[0,2].split(':')[1]`
to get the substance name, however it will become a tedious exercise when the data is in different columns and rows and the split delimiter needs to be altered for each dataframe.

Is there a way to extract this data (substrings) from strings without having to specify the columns and rows and how do I extract a numeric substring from a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd create custom function that searches `pd.Series` for string values and then use regular expression to find the correct items.  E.g.:

```py
import re


def find_project_and_date(series):
    for v in series:
        if not isinstance(v, str):
            continue
        project = re.search(r"project:\s*(45\d{2})", v)
        date = re.search(r"date:\s*(.*?\d{4})\b", v)

        if project and date:
            yield project.group(1), date.group(1)


# find first occurrence of `project` and `date`
out = next(m for c in df.columns if (m := next(find_project_and_date(df[c]), None)))
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
('4568', '7 January 2023')
```

Answer (score 1):

An option might be to flatten with [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), then rely on `project`/`date` to [`extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) the information (everything after the keyword until the next keyword) and convert [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
out = (df
       .stack()
       .str.extractall(r'\b(project|date): *((?:[^:](?!\w+:))+)')
       .set_index(0)[1].to_dict()
       )
```

*NB. This is assuming only one match per dataframe, if you can have several it's easy to handle them but you have to clarify how.*

Output:

```
{'project': '4568', 'date': '7 January 2023'}
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TfvfdF/1)